# AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hello I am i doing a proof of concept with AWS's EC2 and Loadbalancer.  I have a wildfly quickstart running on 2 different EC2 instances.  They work fine, in that i can go to them directly in my browser and get the sites to come up. One says hello server 1 and the other 2.  Running on port 8080.

I have a load balancer set up and it sees my instances and the healthcheck i have in place says they're working.

The configuration is: 80 (HTTP) forwarding to 8080 (HTTP)

When i go to the dns entry + health check path (HTTP:80/wildfly-helloworld/HelloWorld) for the load balancer in my browser it times out.

The bizarre thing again is that it shows my instances as "In Service" and healthy.

Also security on the load balancer is allows ALL inbound and outbound traffic.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried HTTP:80/wildfly-helloworld/HelloWorld? Since you're forwarding port 80, not 8080.

Comment: Yes i'm doing http:// lb-dnsname/wildfly-helloworld/HelloWorld.  I updated my question, i see the confusion.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the port 8080 visible to only your IP or to the world?

Comment: @RakeshBollampally to the world as i can go directly to it.  
[server1](http://54.172.183.12:8080/wildfly-helloworld/HelloWorld),
[server2](http://54.172.38.133:8080/wildfly-helloworld/HelloWorld)
ELB Record is:   
tmp-loadbal-1936927691.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

Comment: @SteveHolt, I've just tried to open the 3 addresses on your previous comment, and they are working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer found here:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=579018#579018

In short the security on the load balancers were off.